# NPOI 2.2.1 generates incorrect XLSX file

Tags: c#, npoi

I have NPOI 2.2.1 and I realized that when generating XLSX file and opening with Excel 2013, a message box telling that a problem was encountered but Excel could try to recover from it. When I click  "Yes", the sheet is finally shown.

This is the code:

```
        IWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook();
        ISheet sheet = workbook.CreateSheet(this.Title);

        using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
        {
            workbook.Write(exportData);
            return exportData.GetBuffer();
        }
```

As you see, I am only creating the workbook, adding a sheet and then returning the bytes array. That array is stored in file using this code:

```
            string targetFile = System.IO.Path.Combine(System.IO.Path.GetTempPath(), String.Concat(btnExportar.Tag, "_", DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss"), ".xlsx"));
            System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(targetFile, xls.GetExcelData());
```

With XLS files there is no problem.

Regards
Jaime

Answer (score 2):

The problem is not with NPOI, but with your use of [GetBuffer()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.getbuffer(v=vs.110).aspx). That is not the method you want to use for this purpose, as GetBuffer() returns the raw buffer underlying the memory stream (usually oversized), *without cutting it off at the current position of the stream*. This will leave uninitialized data at the end, causing the error message in Excel.

The get all the bytes from a MemoryStream, use [ToArray()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.memorystream.toarray(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
using (var exportData = new MemoryStream())
{
    workbook.Write(exportData);
    // return exportData.GetBuffer();
    return exportData.ToArray();
}
```